# What is a "false asynchronous" method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, parallel-processing

I read this [article](https://www.hexacta.com/task-run-vs-async-await/) that provides this example:

```
class MyService
{
  public int CalculateMandelbrot()
  {
    // Tons of work to do in here!
    for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; ++i);
    return 42;
  }
 
  public Task CalculateMandelbrotAsync()
  {
    return Task.Run(() => CalculateMandelbrot());
  }
}
```

It describes this as:

> A “false asynchronous method” is being created because what it is doing is wrapping a synchronous method inside another thread (different from the UI).

It then says:

> A recommended implementation is shown in Figure 6. Due to the initial
> problem, which was not blocking the thread of UI, the solution falls
> in the same UI and not in the service implementation.

which is referring to this method:

```
private async void GetMandelbrot() //Called from UI
{
  await Task.Run(() => myService.CalculateMandelbrot());
}
```

Why is the first one "false asynchronous" but not the 2nd one?

Don't both of them create a new task that can do nothing else other than `CalculateMandelbrot()`?

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html  and maybe https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; ++i);
    return 42;`  ?? ;-)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen it's just an example. It's not about actually calculating Mandelbrot.

Comment: A service shouldn't pretend to be what it is not, and it shouldn't know anything about the UI layer. It's the callers job to ensure long running tasks are started on the correct thread.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think 'false asynchronous' is a commonly used term (I've never heard it), nor clearly defined here.

My take on the article - they are referring to the first method as false asynchronous, because it does not actually have the async/await keywords.  The second does, so it's 'true' asynchronous (again, I don't really like these terms).

When you use the async and await keywords though, *a lot* goes on under the hood of the code to create a state machine to free up a thread, that another thread can then pick up and resume execution on when the operation is ready to continue.

Comment: I didn't downvote you but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a direct answer to the question as SO would prefer, but I feel like the question itself is very misled.  I'm hoping to give OP more information to do more research into async/await themselves and test how it affects a UI-thread-based application

Comment: You can have `public async Task CalculateMandelbrotAsync() { await Task.Run(() => CalculateMandelbrot()); }` (that is, *with* the `await` keyword), and it will be just as fake as the original version. Please see the articles mentioned in the [top comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69519180/what-is-a-false-asynchronous-method/69519526#comment122877498_69519180).